# MYSQL: retrieve all the users details with the details of the first sale for each user by date, 2 tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to retrieve all the users details with the details of the first sale for each user by date.

Mysql tables:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DMFKl.png)

my code:

```
SELECT u.id,u.name,u.email,s.amount,s.date 
FROM users u 
INNER JOIN sales s ON u.id=s.user_id 
ORDER BY u.id,s.date
```

what its return:

> [{"id":"1","name":"aaa","email":"aaa@gmail.com","amount":"5600","date":"2019-11-11"},{"id":"1","name":"aaa","email":"aaa@gmail.com","amount":"3000","date":"2020-01-08"},{"id":"2","name":"bbb","email":"bbb@gmail.com","amount":"6000","date":"2019-12-15"},{"id":"2","name":"bbb","email":"bbb@gmail.com","amount":"1000","date":"2020-06-05"},{"id":"3","name":"ccc","email":"ccc@gmail.com","amount":"7500","date":"2019-09-02"},{"id":"4","name":"ddd","email":"ddd@gmail.com","amount":"5000","date":"2019-03-12"},{"id":"4","name":"ddd","email":"ddd@gmail.com","amount":"4000","date":"2020-04-21"}]

I want to get the earliest date row of each id,like that:

> [{"id":"1","name":"aaa","email":"aaa@gmail.com","amount":"5600","date":"2019-11-11"},{"id":"2","name":"bbb","email":"bbb@gmail.com","amount":"6000","date":"2019-12-15"},{"id":"3","name":"ccc","email":"ccc@gmail.com","amount":"7500","date":"2019-09-02"},{"id":"4","name":"ddd","email":"ddd@gmail.com","amount":"5000","date":"2019-03-12"}]>

help someone?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a query that finds the first sales ID for each user as an inline view (a query in the from clause) and join that inline view to the two tables in question. Like this:

```
select    u.*,
          s.amount,
          s.date
from      users                         u
     join (
            select    user_id,
                      min(date) as min_date
            from      sales
            group by  user_id
          )                             v
     join sales                         s
       on u.user_id = v.user_id
      and s.date = v.min_date;
```

Comment: thank you Brain for the quick reply. the query above not working for me :/ any idea why?

Comment: Not if you don't tell me why it doesn't "work" for you. Why does it not work?

Comment: when I write that query you provided me the output will be 1 row per ID but the date is not the earliest date, for example, id 1 gets the 2020-01-08 and not the 2019-11-11, so I change the min() to max() and for IDs 1,2,3 all good now but for ID 4 got the same issue like ID 1 with the min() function (its display 2020-04-21 and not the earliest, 2019-03-12).

Comment: I had presumed the sales ID was an auto increment integer which, naturally, would ascend with time. Somehow you seem to have a situation where sales ID #1 can occur after sales ID #2. That's bizarre, given that the number 1 comes before the number 2. I am not sure how that is possible, but nevertheless, you can instead pull the minimum date (rather than ID) and join on that. I have edited the query to that effect.

Comment: now it's working :) Thanks for the explanation for understanding and for your time to help me with that issue.